# Executing python code with command line arguments?

Tags: python, compilation

I have python code that takes 3 command line arguments. I am on linux, and I can't figure out how to execute the file. I have compiled with 
python -m py_compile MyFile.py and this puts a MyFile.pyc file on my desktop, but there doesn't seem to be anything I can execute. I have tried ./MyFile.pyc arg1 arg2 arg3, but the command line says permission denied. I then tried 
python MyFile.py arg1 arg2 arg3, and the command line accepts this but doesn't print anything, even though the first line of Main is a print? Am I somehow not printing correctly? I really just need to be able to execute this 1 file and give it arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Invoking the python command with the script as the first argument, followed by your script arguments should work, e.g. `python MyScript.py _args_`.

As an alternative, you could add a shebang at the top of the file, and make it executable with `chmod +x <script>`,  then you could run it with `./MyScript.py _args_`.

Take as a reference the following script, which should print the arguments received:

```
import sys

for n, arg in enumerate(sys.argv):
    print "Arg %d: %s" % (n, arg)
```